# Error: Failed to lookup view "main" in views directory "./views"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have made the handlebars config in my index.js that I think was made correctly, but I continue to get this error where my main.hbs dont get found

Here's my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars');
const app = express();


app.engine("handlebars", engine())
app.set("view engine", "handlebars")
app.set("views", "./views")

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render('main')
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Servidor na porta 3000')
})
```

Project structure is built this way:

```
.
├── index.js
└── views
    ├── home.handlebars
    └── layouts
        └── main.handlebars
```

Complete log error

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "main" in views directory "./views"
    at Function.render (C:\Users\lopes\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\JS\VanillaJS-Crud\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\lopes\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\JS\VanillaJS-Crud\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1017:7)
    at C:\Users\lopes\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\JS\VanillaJS-Crud\index.js:13:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\lopes\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\JS\VanillaJS-Crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\lopes\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\JS\VanillaJS-Crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\lopes\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\JS\VanillaJS-Crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\lopes\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\JS\VanillaJS-Crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\lopes\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\JS\VanillaJS-Crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\lopes\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\JS\VanillaJS-Crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)
    at next (C:\Users\lopes\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\JS\VanillaJS-Crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: I will edit the question and post the error log message

Comment: The error is clear: `Failed to lookup view "main" in views directory "./views"`. You don't have a main.handlebar file in the views folder

Comment: Actually,I do have a main.hbs in my views folder

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here. It's not intended for you to render your layouts directly with a `.render` call. You should be passing a view - like `home` - to your render call and the view engine will make sure it gets wrapped by the layout.