# Handlebars not a function error in express-handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, viewengine

**my code,got from a website**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
//Loads the handlebars module
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
//Sets our app to use the handlebars engine
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
//Sets handlebars configurations (we will go through them later on)
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({
layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',
}));
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//Serves the body of the page aka "main.handlebars" to the container //aka "index.handlebars"
res.render('main', {layout : 'index'});
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening to port ${port}`));
```

**showing an error that**

```
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({
                         ^

TypeError: handlebars is not a function
```

How can i solve these problem tried lots of solutions but still not working

*My directory looks like*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
//Loads the handlebars module
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
```

You can setup handlebar as

```
var hbs = handlebars.create();
app.engine("handlebars", hbs.engine);
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/views"));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//Serves the body of the page aka "main.handlebars" to the container //aka "index.handlebars"
res.render('main', {layout : 'index'});
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening to port ${port}`));
```

Comment: "Failed to lookup view "main" in views directory"  what is the error

Comment: You can check the same error in this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529172/error-failed-to-lookup-view-main-in-views-directory-views)